# Nuxtjs axios get status code from response from Rest API

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework, axios, nuxt.js

I'm calling a Rest API that returns status codes. Some of them don't return Content in body. If i make in postman my calls i can get some status code like 202 Accepted, 200 OK... how can get it in Nuxtjs with axios.
Any help would be very appreciated.
[image]
My code:

```
    async register() {
  const response = await this.$axios.$post('register/', {
  user: this.user,
  })
  console.log(response)
  // this.$nuxt.refresh()
  // this.status = response.status
  // if (this.status === 'register success') {
  //   this.$router.push('/login/')
  // }
}
```

and nothing show up :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be "this.$axios.post". There is not such method as $post.

From the official docs:

```
axios.post('/user', {
firstName: 'Fred',
lastName: 'Flintstone'})
```